# Oracle PLSQL Cascade Delete doesn't work?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, ddl, cascade

I have some tables with foreign keys which should be deleted. I Put the "on delete cascade" everywhere I needed it, but when I try to Drop the Table i get following error:

```
*Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a table with unique or
           primary keys referenced by foreign keys in another table.
```

This is the Table I want to drop:

```
DROP TABLE Author;
CREATE TABLE Author (
    id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    date_of_death DATE NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Author_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And this is the Table that is in relation to the Author table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    author NUMBER(4) NULL,
    title VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    ISBN VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL,
    book_language VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    book_genre VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Book_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT Book_Author FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES Author(id) ON DELETE cascade
);
```

Comment: `drop table author cascade constraints`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` is a DDL. It has nothing to do with `DELETE` (DML) (affected by the way you created the foreign key constraint).

Drop child table first; then drop its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it now with help from @a_horse_with_no_name 
If you have the same issue, just write

`drop table table_name cascade constraints;`